# Problem backing up large database using pg_dump

Tags: spring-boot, postgresql-9.5

I am using the following technologies

1. Java 1.8
2. Spring Boot 1.5
3. PostgreSQL 9.5

I am facing a problem while backing up a large database using pg_dump, however, it is working fine for small database.  Following is the code that I am using at present.

```
ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

commands.add("C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.5\\bin\\pg_dump");
commands.add("-h");
commands.add(ipaddress);
commands.add("-p");
commands.add(port);
commands.add("-U");
commands.add(username);
commands.add("-F");
commands.add("c");
commands.add("-b");
commands.add("-f");
commands.add("backup.dump");
commands.add("-d");
commands.add(database);

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.environment().put("PGPASSWORD", password);

Process process = pb.start();

try (BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()))) {}


process.waitFor();
process.destroy();
```

What appears to be happening is that the service for backup is being called twice, one after another, and quitting without properly backing up the database.  It also doesn't return call back to the EJB.  Am I missing something here, or should I change the way I am doing things?

Comment: Maybe you should add the info from `buf` (which you are ignoring right now) to you question?  Also there is an [outputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) which might help to identify the problem.

Comment: @Luuk: Sadly, the code doesn't  come out of  `Process process = pb.start();` before quitting.